# How can I continue a partial, interrupted download of Yosemite?

Tags: macos

I was trying to download OS X Yosemite. It is very big - more than 5GB.

The download did not succeed due to some problem in internet connection. Only 2.5 GB is downloaded and I wanted to continue from where it stopped. I closed the Mac App Store and reopened. I lost what was downloaded till that time. I want to know where it is stored in my Mac so that I could start from there. It saves me lot of time and internet download usage, since it is a limited internet plan.

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in the Application folder - if it doesn't continue, then delete the already downloaded file, and retry from the App Store again.

Answer (score 0):

To resume your download:

1. Open the Mac App Store.
2. From the Store menu, choose Sign In.
3. Enter your Apple ID and password.
4. Click Purchases to get to your Purchases Page.
   [image]
5. Click the Resume button next to the app name.
   [image]

*Source:* http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202159